# Autospec does nothing when I run

Tags: ruby, autotest, zentest

I have failing tests that show up when I do a 'rake spec' or the like.

However when I run autospec it outputs the following then does nothing and returns me to the command prompt.

> $ autospec

**(Not running features.  To run features in autotest, set AUTOFEATURE=true.)
loading autotest/rails_rspec
style: RailsRspec**

How do I get autospec running?

The gems I have installed are:

autotest (4.3.2)
autotest-growl (0.2.5)
rspec (1.3.0)
rspec-rails (1.3.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since installing bundler/Rails 3, to run autospec the following command is needed:

```
$> bundle exec autospec
```

Answer (score 1):

I once solved this problem removing the `test` directory. Give it a try. Also run `autospec -v` to see which paths he is looking at.

Comment: Great feedback, unfortunatley in this case no 'test' directory.

Comment: Bummer. I did quite a search when I had this problem and I found some advices (though it didn't solve my problems), check them out: https://rspec.lighthouseapp.com/projects/5645/tickets/689-autospec-fails-silently-without-zentest http://groups.google.com/group/rspec/browse_thread/thread/edf132f95bd3f4c7

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to install autotest-rails